# Separate BigDecimal Fraction Part

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I need to separate fractional part from `BigDecimal` and convert to `Integer`.

Eg:

```
1.05(BigDecimal) => 5(int)
1.30(BigDecimal) => 30(int)
```

Note: Decimal part won't exceed 2 digits

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
int i = bigDecimal
    .minus(new BigDecimal(bigDecimal.intValue())
    .multiply(new BigDecimal(100))
    .intValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is an easier way but this works:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("1.05");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("1.3");
System.out.println(a.movePointRight(2).intValue() % 100);
System.out.println(b.movePointRight(2).intValue() % 100);

>> 5
>> 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
BigDecimal big = new BigDecimal("1.5");
BigDecimal fraction =big.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE);

System.out.println(fraction.multiply(new BigDecimal(10).pow(big.precision()-1)).intValue());
```